# Bad backlinks although not yet registered in search engines?

Tags: seo, backlinks, negative-seo

I have a website that is hosted online but not yet registered in the search engines. But my website already has backlinks. Bad backlinks. Backlinks that have zero relation to my website. How can this happen? My website can't be found by a competitor or something through the search engines yet. So the website is not known to anyone yet. How can this be possible?

Comment: There is no such thing as  "registering your site with search engines".  Search engines discover sites through links to them.  You can create a Google Search Console account or Bing Webmaster Tools account which will show you information about how your site is doing in the search engine.  However, if you don't do so, search engines will find and index your site anyway.

Comment: Do you have a domain name for your site?  Is it freshly registered?    Does it have any history (previous registrations)?

Comment: How are you determining the backlinks?

Comment: Adding to the existing answers: links that are irrelevant aren't necessarily "bad", the will just be ignored by Google. Links start to become "bad" when you have a big percentage of spammy links, that appear constantly and/or suddenly and even those tend to be ignored by Google for the most part.